# convert inorder equation to preorder equation with mongoose query syntax

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, inorder, preorder

I have an javascript object as follows. please note the spaces in the string.

```
find = { search: "name:someName and ( place:someplace or place:someotherplace )" }
```

i want to convert the string to the following

```
query={ 
        $and: [  
                {name:'someName'} , 
                {$or: [
                       {place:'someplace'}, 
                       {place:'someotherplace'} 
                      ]
                }
              ]
      }
```

I would like generic code which works for any such AND, OR equations and converts them into respective mongoose queries. That is I want a inorder equation to be converted into preorder equation and then modified to get mongoose query.

Comment: The [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) is one way to do it. It's usually used to convert from infix to postfix, but you can adapt it to generate prefix notation. The algorithm is solid, and reasonably easy to implement.

Comment: I think i got an idea. Thank you.!!

Comment: Come to think of it, you can construct your desired syntax using infix-to-postfix. Essentially what you want to do is construct an expression tree and then output it in JSON format.

Comment: exactlyy. Thats is what i thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function formQuery(searchString) {
    let infixArray = convertStringtoInfix(searchString);
    if (bracketChecker(infixArray)) {
        let postFixArray = convertInfixToPostfix(infixArray);
        let finalQuery = convertPostfixToQuery(postFixArray);
        return finalQuery;
    } else {
        return 'bracket mismatch';
    }
};

function bracketChecker(searchArray) {
    let flag = true;
    let stack = [];
    searchArray.forEach((element) => {
        if (element == '(') {
            stack.push(element);
        }
        if (element == ')') {
            if (stack.length > 0) {
                stack.pop();
            } else {
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    });
    if (stack.length > 0) {
        flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
}

function convertPostfixToQuery(postFixArray) {
    let stack = [];
    postFixArray.forEach((element) => {
        if (typeof element == 'object') {
            //makes it regex ==========================================
            // Object.keys(element).forEach(function(key) {
            //  if (element[key] == 'true') {
            //      element[key] = true;
            //  } else if (element[key] == 'false') {
            //      element[key] = false;
            //  } else {
            //      element[key] = new RegExp(element[key], 'i');
            //  }
            // });
            //=========================================================
            stack.push(element);
        } else {
            let obj = {};
            let lastelement = stack.pop();
            let secondLastElement = stack.pop();
            obj[element] = [ lastelement, secondLastElement ];
            stack.push(obj);
        }
    });
    return stack[0];
    // return { and: /a/i };
}

function convertInfixToPostfix(infixArray) {
    let outputQueue = [];
    let operatorStack = [];
    infixArray.forEach((element) => {
        if (typeof element == 'object') {
            outputQueue.push(element);
        } else if (element == '(') {
            operatorStack.push(element);
        } else if (element == ')') {
            let paranMismatch = false;
            while (operatorStack.length > 0 && operatorStack[operatorStack.length - 1] != '(') {
                outputQueue.push(operatorStack.pop());
                if (operatorStack.length == 0) {
                    paranMismatch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (paranMismatch) {
                return 'mismatch';
            }
            if (operatorStack[operatorStack.length - 1] == '(') {
                operatorStack.pop();
            }
        } else if (element == 'and' || element == 'or') {
            while (
                operatorStack.length > 0 &&
                operatorStack[operatorStack.length - 1] != '(' &&
                operatorStack[operatorStack.length - 1].length >= element.length
            ) {
                outputQueue.push(operatorStack.pop());
            }
            operatorStack.push(element);
        } else {
            return 'mismatch';
        }
    });
    operatorStack.reverse();
    operatorStack.forEach((element) => {
        if (element == '(') {
            return 'mismatch';
        } else {
            outputQueue.push(element);
        }
    });
    outputQueue = outputQueue.map((element) => {
        if (element == 'and' || element == 'or') return '$' + element;
        else return element;
    });
    return outputQueue;
}

function convertStringtoInfix(str) {
    let output = '';
    [ ...str ].forEach((c) => {
        if (c == '(' || c == ')') {
            output += ' ' + c + ' ';
        } else {
            output += c;
        }
    });
    output = output.split(' ');
    output = output.filter((ele) => ele != '');
    output = output.map((ele) => {
        if (ele.toLowerCase() == 'and' || ele.toLowerCase() == 'or') {
            return ele.toLowerCase();
        } else if (ele == '(' || ele == ')') {
            return ele;
        } else {
            let key = ele.split(':')[0];
            let value = ele.split(':')[1];

            let obj = {};
            obj[key] = value;

            return obj;
        }
    });
    return output;
}
let search = 'name:someName and ( place:someplace or place:someotherplace )'
console.log(formQuery(search))
```

and the output is:-

```
{
        "$and": [
            {
                "$or": [
                    {
                        "place": "someotherplace"
                    },
                    {
                        "place": "someplace"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "someName"
            }
        ]
    }
```